# how to gather first part of second line of output in a bash script and set to variable

Tags: bash, mac, digital-ocean

I have the following command I need to run from a script to create a droplet from digital ocean:

```
RG@iPhone-3 Projects % doctl compute droplet create testdroplet --image ubuntu-18-04-x64 --size s-1vcpu-1gb --region nyc1
ID           Name           Public IPv4    Private IPv4    Public IPv6    Memory    VCPUs    Disk    Region    Image                     VPC UUID    Status    Tags    Features    Volumes
233560705    testdroplet                                                  1024      1        25      nyc1      Ubuntu 18.04 (LTS) x64                new
```

from inside a script, I need to gather the id 233560705 and set to a bash variable to be used elsewhere in the script. How can this be done in bash? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
variable=$(doctl compute droplet create testdroplet --image ubuntu-18-04-x64 --size s-1vcpu-1gb --region nyc1 | awk 'NR==2 { print $1 }')
```

The `awk` acript prints the first field (`$1`) of the second line (condition `NR==2` where `NR` is the record number = line number).